# Google Gantt chart duration

Tags: javascript, charts, google-api, google-visualization

My goal is to give the end time of a task (deadline) and how long it will take to finish it (duration), so I give Google Grantt Charts an end time and duration, because this should [compute the start time](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/ganttchart#computing-startendduration). However, this doesn't work and it will set *today* as start time and not *end time - duration = start time*

As a workaround I give a start time, **negative duration** and end time as *null* 
(dToMs() = convert days to milliseconds):

```
data.addRows([
  ['1', 'Name', 'Resource', new Date(2016, 6, 13), null, dToMs(-3), 0, null]
]);
```

This works, but if you hover over it the date goes from *Jul 13* to *10, 2016* which is wrong.

Edit: Workaround

```
// calcStartTime
function cST(date, duration) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() - duration);
  return result;
}

...

['1', 'Name', 'Resource', cST(variableToEndTime, variableToDuration), new Date(variableToEndTime), null, 0, null]
```

Comment: Can't you just make a function that calculates and returns the correct Start date, as googles doesn't work? 

`['1', 'Name', 'Resource', startDate(new Date(2016, 6, 13), 3), new Date(2016, 6, 13), null, 0, null]`

And startDate would be something like

`funciton startDate(myDate, duration) { return myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + duration); }`

Or something similar...

Comment: Thanks, already fixed it with a function like yours

`// calcStartTime
    function cST(date, duration) {
      var result = new Date(date);
      result.setDate(result.getDate() - duration);
      return result;
    }`